# Does getting edits rejected as spam/vandalism carry a special penalty?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I see it often in the Stack Exchange review queue that people reject clearly not vandalism/spam edits as vandalism/spam. In and of itself that's already not optimal, because the editor will not learn from that kind of response (if they bother checking).

However, in parallel to the spam/offensive flags, it got me thinking:

1. Does having your edit rejected as spam/vandalism carry a special penalty like a redflag would?
2. If so, should we make that clear to reviewers so they don't use it as a catch-all reason?
3. If not, should it carry one?

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234932/if-i-see-a-spam-vandalism-suggested-edit-should-i-do-anything-extra-about-it) on Meta SE.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of things that you don#t consider vandalism/spam, but the community does?

Comment: Pretty sure there is no penalty at all, but not confident enough to make it an answer.

Comment: Likely dup on MSE: [Do suggested edits rejected for “vandalism” get flagged for moderators in some way? \[duplicate\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128916/do-suggested-edits-rejected-for-vandalism-get-flagged-for-moderators-in-some-w).  Which itself is a duplicate of [Does the rejection of a suggested edit with the reason “Vandalism” flag the post in any way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109266/does-the-rejection-of-a-suggested-edit-with-the-reason-vandalism-flag-the-post)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, at least not visibly. While spam is pretty clear, vandalism speaks a lot to *intent*, which is a very subjective call to make in the context of an edit. It's not something I'd feel very comfortable carrying an automatic penalty.

We do occasionally review for patterns in edits rejected for "spam / vandalism" as part of helping to keep the spam down. This usually happens when someone complains that a particular (usually small) answer that they wrote has been targeted by spam edit bots, going back through all of 'em helps us narrow down the shady networks.

Worth noting, mods can and do get in touch with people that have a pretty consistently bad edit history in hopes of slowing them down. Since patterns like this are pretty visible in review, it's not long before a human notices and gets someone involved (or raises it here). But you need to be messing up in the dozens pretty consistently before that happens.

Comment: So there is no automatic mechanism in place that alerts a mod whenever person X gets more than Y edits rejected as vandalism in a Z time period?

Comment: Shouldn't spam and vandalism be reported differently then? As they are clearly different as your answer states.