# When should the vandalism reject reason be used?

Tags: discussion, documentation

There isn't a clean cut choice to use the vandalism flag; is it as black and white as the SO spam flag or more gray? I was recently reviewing changes to examples and found several that merely changed the style of the topic without making the actual example any clearer. Perhaps the editor wwas just looking for rep - perhaps not.

Either way, how should users use the vandalism flag?

Comment: relevant or duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327714/does-getting-edits-rejected-as-spam-vandalism-carry-a-special-penalty

Comment: That is not vandalism, avoid using a bazooka to kill a mosquito.  Just reject pointless edits.

Comment: @HansPassant I was mostly asking if the flag was more like a nuclear bomb or a fly swatter

Comment: It is a [bazooka](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Soldier_with_Bazooka_M1.jpg).  Takes out tanks.  Using the proper flag is important to help the mods prioritize their tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not vandalism, although it may be rep farming. **May**.

If the style changes weren't necessary, just reject them. Documentation does not seem to have a "No improvement whatsoever" reject reason like regular edit reviews have, so you'll have to use a custom reason.

Try to keep it professional and polite though. I'm thinking along the lines of:

> Unfortunately, this edit does not make the example more clear.

You could discuss it with the editor in chat, or invite them to Meta. The result of this tends to vary. Some will discuss things professionally, others just raise drama or throw a tantrum.
Either way, if you're going to discuss it with them, be sure to do so in a calm, professional manner. The constructive approach to such a conversation is to assume that they are acting in good faith.