# Is there any penalty for a rejected edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation

Is there any penalty for a wrong edit or rejected edit?
I see that +2 reputation is awarded for an approved edit. But users who have an edit rejected don't get -2 reputation subtracted. There is no information about subtraction in the achievements menu.

Comment: It's at least possible to get edit-banned if you make too many bad edit suggestions.

Comment: Good question. Is this actually documented someplace where we all can see?

Comment: @dfd All of the ways you can gain or lose reputation are documented in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), as well as [this FAQ on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

No, not directly.

Good edits are incentivized with a reputation gain of +2. This happens at the point where the edit is approved. However, [a feature was recently added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/153008) that lets the owner of the post or a moderator retroactively reject an edit, which will remove the 2 points that you gained at the time of its initial acceptance. Still, this isn't a penalty so much as changing history—it's as if your edit was never accepted, so you don't gain the incentive from that.

It's important to note, though, that if you *consistently* suggest bad edits, a moderator is eventually going to notice and probably reach out to you with suggestions on how to make better edits. If that doesn't work and you *still* keep making bad edits, then you will very likely be banned from suggesting any more edits. You might also be *automatically* banned (*i.e.*, without moderator intervention) if a large percentage of your suggested edits are rejected. So that is a penalty, but it doesn't directly affect your reputation.

You won't ever lose reputation points from suggesting bad edits.

Comment: why the removal -2 is not reflected in achievements ..it still shows +2

Comment: If an edit approval is later overridden by a post owner or moderator, then it will show up in your history.

Comment: @CodyGray When you say *"a moderator is eventually going to notice"*, what do you mean, do you refer to it being pointed out by a moderator flag or do you have other tools at your disposal to find bad edits?

Comment: A user's complete edit history is in their profile, @Nick, so it isn't hard to find patterns. But we do have to go looking, and there are various things that can cause us to do that, including flags from other users.

Comment: Ahh I see; was wondering why people were able to override my decisions. TBH I don't think that was a good idea; I keep seeing people approving rightfully rejected edits (edits which add poor formatting get rejected, then approved by OP).

Comment: What happens if someone's edit was rejected as spam or deliberate vandalism? Is there a penalty for that?

Comment: @EJoshuaS No, not directly. :-) Again, if that happens a lot, a moderator would probably step in. But there's no rep loss penalty, and the system doesn't treat one rejection reason any different from the others.

Comment: That seems slightly odd to me, given how significant the penalties for having a spam flag on a post upheld are. But, then again, getting a spam flag upheld requires a lot more people (or a moderator) to agree to the flag whereas accepting that as a reject reason only requires two reviewers.

Comment: @EJoshuaS That's a fair point. I'm not really sure why it is not. Probably because it wasn't worth writing a bunch of code to special case it, not to mention the problem of people picking that reason for things that are not actually spam and would not deserve the penalty. [Tim Post confirms here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327714/does-getting-edits-rejected-as-spam-vandalism-carry-a-special-penalty).

Comment: Is that the same reponse at this time?